# Spark Dataframe sliding window over pair of rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, event-log

I have an eventlog in csv consisting of three columns `timestamp`, `eventId` and `userId`.

What I would like to do is append a new column `nextEventId` to the dataframe.

An example eventlog:

```
eventlog = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Array((20160101, 1, 0),(20160102,3,1),(20160201,4,1),(20160202, 2,0))).toDF("timestamp", "eventId", "userId")
eventlog.show(4)

|timestamp|eventId|userId|
+---------+-------+------+
| 20160101|      1|     0|
| 20160102|      3|     1|
| 20160201|      4|     1|
| 20160202|      2|     0|
+---------+-------+------+
```

The desired endresult would be:

```
|timestamp|eventId|userId|nextEventId|
+---------+-------+------+-----------+
| 20160101|      1|     0|          2|
| 20160102|      3|     1|          4|
| 20160201|      4|     1|        Nil|
| 20160202|      2|     0|        Nil|
+---------+-------+------+-----------+
```

So far I've been messing around with sliding windows but can't figure out how to compare 2 rows...

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("userId").orderBy(asc("timestamp")) //should be a sliding window over 2 rows...
val nextNodes = second($"eventId").over(w) //should work if there are only 2 rows
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're looking for is `lead` (or `lag`). Using window you already defined:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lead

eventlog.withColumn("nextEventId", lead("eventId", 1).over(w))
```

For true sliding window (like sliding average) you can use `rowsBetween` or `rangeBetween` clauses of the window definition but it is not really required here. Nevertheless example usage could be something like this:

```
val w2 =  Window.partitionBy("userId")
  .orderBy(asc("timestamp"))
  .rowsBetween(-1, 0)

avg($"foo").over(w2)
```